# When would a PostGIS geometry compare using ~= return true when ST_Equals returns false?

Tags: postgis, geometry, comparison

I have a couple of featureclasses in a 10.2 geodatabase/PostgreSQL 9.2.2 database and I've been struggling with the FeatureCompare tool--it is telling me geometries are different on some features where I know them to be at least spatially equal.

Luckily, I have an ID and I could join between the 2 tables in PGAdmin and compare geometry.  The `~=` opreator and the ST_Equals both return true for every row.  Then I modified 1 feature by moving 1 vertex 800 ft to the South.

When I run my query, ST_Equals returns false which is what I expect.  But `~=` still returns true??? Why is that?

```
select t1.shape,t2.shape ,(t1.shape ~= t2.shape) as exactequal , ST_Equals(t1.shape , t2.shape) spatialequal, (t1.shape = t2.shape) bndequal
from  pg.Test1 t1
inner join pt.Bnd2 t2
on t1.polygon_id=t2.polygon_id
where t1.objectid = 6389
```

[image]

I trying to figure out if this is a bug or if I'm misunderstanding the operators.

*"PostgreSQL 9.2.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 64-bit"

"POSTGIS="2.0.4" GEOS="3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r0" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.10.0, released 2013/04/24"*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the doc says ~= only compares bounding boxes.
So if you move a point in a way that it doesn't change the bounding box ~= still returns true.

Comment: Maybe i was looking at old docs. The one i was looking at said equal sign only was bounding box compare.

Comment: Sure enough, I was looking at 1.3 docs: `The "~=" operator is the "same as" operator. It tests actual geometric equality of two features.`. And 2.0 docs have it as: `Returns TRUE if A's bounding box is the same as B's.`.