# What is the PostGIS 2.x equivalent of the pre-PostGIS 1.5 ~= operator?

Tags: postgis, geometry, comparison

Stemming from my other question: [When would a PostGIS geometry compare using ~= return true when ST_Equals returns false?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/85017/31), what is the PostGIS 2.x equivalent of the  pre-PostGIS 1.5  ~= operator?

It appears that from 1.4 to 1.5, the `~=` operator changed from an "exactly equal" to an "bnd equal":

For example, in v1.3:
http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.3/ch06.html#id439812
`The "~=" operator is the "same as" operator. It tests actual geometric equality of two features. So if A and B are the same feature, vertex-by-vertex, the operator returns true.`

and in 1.5 and later:
http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.5/ST_Geometry_Same.html
`Returns TRUE if A's bounding box is the same as B's.`

I'm mostly interested in [PostGIS2.0](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/reference.html#Operators), but I'm not tagging a specific version and leaving it open.

Comment: It's worth noting that both [`ST_Equals`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_Equals.html) and [`ST_OrderingEquals`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_OrderingEquals.html) provide a very similar operation to what you're asking for but, from the examples they provide, clearly indicate that the comparison is not made vertex-to-vertex. However, is it possible they suit your needs?

Comment: Actually, `ST_Equals` suits my needs, but asked the question for future reference/curiosity. I didn't know about `ST_OrderingEquals`, but that looks more practical than a vertex-by-vertex comparison.

Comment: Mind turning this knowledge into an answer, @Arthur ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does seem that the "[test] for actual geometric equality of the two features" is missing from later versions, but according to [this article from Boundless](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/equality.html) (formerly OpenGeo), **the function** `ST_Equals` **can be thought of as testing for "exact equality"** even though, [according to the documentation](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_Equals.html), it does not make this comparison vertex-to-vertex.

For instance, in this example, from the PostGIS 2.0 documentation, these linestrings are considered equal even though there is one vertex not shared between them. **Presumably, in any case where such vertices fall on the same, shared boundary, the geometries are considered equal.**

```
SELECT ST_Equals(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0, 10 10)'),
        ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0, 5 5, 10 10)'));
 st_equals
-----------
 t
(1 row)
```

`ST_OrderingEquals` provides the same result with the same example, but this function is actually more constrained: **it tests both for "equal geometry" and 
that the "points are in the same directional order."** [The article on Equality](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/equality.html) from Boundless is recommended.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on [Arthur's](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/12764/arthur) answer, I was able to compare using md5 hashes:

```
SELECT ST_Equals(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0, 10 10)'),
         ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0, 5 5, 10 10)')) 
        ,(md5(ST_AsEWKB(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0, 5 5, 10 10)'))) 
          = md5(ST_AsEWKB(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0, 10 10)')))) md5hashcompare
```

[image]

MD5 collisions may be an issue. I didn't see any SHA functions, but maybe there's a crypto extension to PostgreSQL that has it (which would reduce but not entirely eliminate the chance of a collision).

Answer (score 1):

ST_Equals is not the same as the old ~=.  The equivalent to the old ~= is ST_OrderingEquals.

ST_Equals requires your geometries be valid and will return true as long as they occupy the same space.  ST_OrderingEquals (and the ~= operator) were more like binary equality (not quite), that utilize spatial index.

Comment: I don't think ST_OrderingEquals  behaves exactly as the old `~=`.  Look at the second example here: http://postgis.net/docs/ST_OrderingEquals.html.  ST_OrderingEquals returns true in this case, old `~=` returns false.

Comment: Jay, are you comparing the current ~= with ST_OrderingEquals?  They are no longer the same.  The behavior of ~= changed around 1.4 (and I remember it because I was particularly annoyed by the change).  In 1.3 and around 1.4 they meant the same thing.  Then the recheck was taken out so the new ~= really became a bounding box equality (except it used an index unlike (=) (only if you weren't upgrading from 1.3).  So there was a period around 1.4-1.5 (where you may get the old behavior if you did a soft upgrade and you got the new behavior if you did a hard upgrade or installed a fresh pot).

Comment: On closer inspection I think I misread your comment.  Are you saying in the old for ```SELECT ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0, 10 10)')  ~= ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0, 0 0, 10 10)');  ```   you are getting false? Unfortunately I don't have a 1.3 version to test.  That could be some implementation change of the actual ST_OrderingEquals.